# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE' once added variable for total

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, shopping-cart, sql-update, aspxgridview

I'm having this problem where once I've calculated to display (Quantity * Price) As Total FROM ShoppingCart, it managed to display the total for the total item user purchased but I couldn't update or delete at the column and when I update it straight away give me this error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'"

I'll Provide the code here:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
                    AllowSorting="True">
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" 
                            SortExpression="ProductID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" 
                            SortExpression="UserName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="InsertDate" HeaderText="InsertDate" 
                            SortExpression="InsertDate" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" 
                            SortExpression="Quantity" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" 
                            SortExpression="Price" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderID" HeaderText="OrderID" 
                            SortExpression="OrderID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total" 
                            SortExpression="Total" />
                    </Columns>
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                    ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
                    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [ShoppingCart] WHERE [CartID] = @original_CartID AND [ProductID] = @original_ProductID AND [UserName] = @original_UserName AND [InsertDate] = @original_InsertDate AND [Quantity] = @original_Quantity AND [Price] = @original_Price AND [OrderID] = @original_OrderID AND [Total]= @original_Total" 
                    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [ShoppingCart] ([ProductID], [UserName], [InsertDate], [Quantity], [Price], [OrderID], [Total]) VALUES (@ProductID, @UserName, @InsertDate, @Quantity, @Price, @OrderID, @Total)" 
                    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT  [ProductID], [UserName], [InsertDate], [Quantity], [Price], [OrderID], (Quantity * Price) As Total FROM [ShoppingCart]" 


                    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [ShoppingCart] SET [ProductID] = @ProductID, [UserName] = @UserName, [InsertDate] = @InsertDate, [Quantity] = @Quantity, [Price] = @Price, [OrderID] = @OrderID, [Total]= @Total, WHERE [CartID] = @original_CartID AND [ProductID] = @original_ProductID AND [UserName] = @original_UserName AND [InsertDate] = @original_InsertDate AND [Quantity] = @original_Quantity AND [Price] = @original_Price AND [OrderID] = @original_OrderID AND [Total]= @Total">
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CartID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_ProductID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_UserName" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_InsertDate" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Quantity" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Price" Type="Decimal" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_OrderID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Total" Type="Decimal" />
                    </DeleteParameters>
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="InsertDate" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Quantity" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Price" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="OrderID" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Total" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="InsertDate" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Quantity" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="Decimal" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="OrderID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Total" Type="Decimal" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CartID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_ProductID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_UserName" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_InsertDate" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Quantity" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Price" Type="Decimal" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_OrderID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Total" Type="Decimal" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Do guide me in this i dont know what they mean by the error.This is for the admin who can update or delete in the shopping cart

Comment: Isn't there an extra comma before the where `... [Total]= @Total, WHERE` ?

Comment: @AlexK. Why didn't you put that as an answer?

Comment: its showing a different one now Invalid column name 'Total'.what am i suppose to replace with the Total column name since it is quantity * price.It can display the total but when comes to editing the quantity column it appears like this...

Comment: and when i change the Total variable to Quantity * Price the error turn to be like this Incorrect syntax near '*'.
Must declare the scalar variable "@original_CartID".please do assist me in this.THanks

Answer (score 1):

problem in your update command

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [ShoppingCart] SET [ProductID] = @ProductID, [UserName] = @UserName, [InsertDate] = @InsertDate, [Quantity] = @Quantity, [Price] = @Price, [OrderID] = @OrderID, [Total]= @Total, WHERE [CartID] = @original_CartID AND [ProductID] = @original_ProductID AND [UserName] = @original_UserName AND [InsertDate] = @original_InsertDate AND [Quantity] = @original_Quantity AND [Price] = @original_Price AND [OrderID] = @original_OrderID AND [Total]= @Total">
```

in query ther is comma before WHERE
find this,

[Total]= **@Total, WHERE** [CartID] = @original_CartID